# AWS CloudSearch - is there a limit to the number of stopwords and synonyms you can add?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

In the Text Options panel of the AWS CloudSearch console you are able to add stopwords, stems and synonyms to the search index via text field inputs. I am able to upload 471 stopwords, but not one more. When I try, the upload times out and the following javascript error is reported:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Error' of null in cs.201212282103.js
```

I am assuming I have hit a limit. Is this documented anywhere? I also have a very large set of synonyms that I was hoping to upload. Is there a limit for synonyms? Is there another method to upload stopwords, stems and synonyms - for example an API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is limits and you can check it on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/Limits.html

```
Stemming dictionary size
The maximum size of a Amazon CloudSearch stemming dictionary is 500 KB.

Stopwords dictionary size
The maximum size of a Amazon CloudSearch stopwords dictionary is 10 KB.

Synonym dictionary size
The maximum size of a Amazon CloudSearch synonym dictionary is 100 KB.
```

But I'm not confirming that you have a limit problem, I'm just answering the other questions. Like you pointed might be a temporary problem with the console.

Answer (score 0):

The CloudSearch Console has a bug (that apparently has not been fixed 6 years later). Fortunately, you can get around by using the AWS CLI.

I just encountered this issue when trying to add some new synonyms. I was afraid I was hitting some sort of limit as I could add the same synonyms to a test analysis scheme which had only a handful of synonyms. But after reading Everton's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14350489/2239183), I saw that my synonym dictionary was no where near the 100 KB limit. And I doubt the OP was hitting the limit either (but the javascript does fail after a certain amount of data, so it is an artificial limit).

So, I contacted AWS Support who asked me to try using AWS CLI to update my analysis scheme. And that worked. Here is the command to be used:

```
aws cloudsearch define-analysis-scheme --domain-name <your-domain-name> --analysis-scheme file://path/to/file.json
```

The structure in your JSON file should be as follows:

```
{ 
  "AnalysisSchemeName": "<your-scheme-name>", 
  "AnalysisSchemeLanguage": "en", 
  "AnalysisOptions": {
    "AlgorithmicStemming": "none"|"minimal"|"light"|"full", 
    "JapaneseTokenizationDictionary": "",
    "Synonyms": "{\"aliases\":{\"baseball\":[\"sport\"],\"basketball\":[\"sport\"],\"football\":[\"sport\"],\"mexican\":[\"food\"],\"pepper\":[\"food\"],\"grill\":[\"food\"]},\"groups\":[[\"travel\",\"vacation\",\"relax\",\"trip\",\"getaway\"],[\"happy\",\"cheerful\",\"joy\",\"joyful\"]]}", 
    "StemmingDictionary": "{}", 
    "Stopwords": "[\"a\",\"an\"]"
  }
}
```

I've left some synonym data to show how to add data for both aliases and groups and the structure for stopwords.

More details can be found on the AWS CLI Command Reference page for [define-analysis-scheme](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/cloudsearch/define-analysis-scheme.html).